# c# how to see which variable that is in the same index as another variable in another list

Tags: c#, list, indexing

example:

```
List<string> myList1 = new List<string>();
List<string> myList2 = new List<string>();

myList1.Add("hello1");
myList1.Add("hello2");

myList2.Add("hello3");
myList2.Add("hello1");
```

my question is how do i get the program to return the same variable that is in the same index as that variable. For example: if i choose hello1 from list1 it should return the variable in the same index in which case is hello3. write if you have any questions or dont understand what i am saying.

Comment: Suggested reading: **[List<T>.IndexOf Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.indexof?view=netcore-3.1)**

Answer (score 1):

```
int index = myList1.FindIndex(a => a == "hello1");
string otherItem = myList2[index];
```

You can use the FindIndex() method to find the index, and then get the string at that index from the other list.

Hope this helped.

Comment: hi, thanks for the help! My problem with this is that mylist2 holds objects. I then get the error: cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'. Could you help me with this?

Comment: @edwardthecoder sure can u show me exactly what list2 and list1 contain

Comment: sure! list 2 contains objects and the class holds two strings, username and password. Here, when i try to see which object is in the same index as the string "index", it shows the error: cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'.

Comment: @edwardthecoder i think you simply need to change `string` to the name of the object that you have. Give that a try. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi again! It worked. I added object in front of "otherItem" as it became an object and it worked. The only thing is that i cant access the strings (username and password) that is in the class. I cant write like: otherItem.username or otherItem.password.